# org.zkoss.zk.device.DeviceNotFoundException: ajax not found

Tags: ajax, zk

When i am running my web project in eclipse i am getting exception

```
org.zkoss.zk.device.DeviceNotFoundException: ajax not found.
```

I am using

> zk6.5.3+Tomcat7+Java7

Answer (score 4):

This exception may be thrown because of multiple versions of ZK libs exist in the classpath. Check this carefully.